# How can I make an <li> not take the entire width?

Tags: css

I am trying to style a `<ul>`'s items. What I am basically trying to do is when i hover the mouse over one `<li>` a subtle border should appear. But the problem is that the border is taking the entire list's width.

Code is:

```css
li:hover {
            border-style: dotted;
            border-width: 0.1rem;
}
```

I have tried to apply `display: inline-block` or other things that came to me, but didn't manage to make it work.

Current behaviour in this image:
[currentBehaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSAKk.png)

What is the solution and what is the cause of the current behaviour? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your **li** is taking the full width of **ul** tag.

You can use

```
width: fit-content;
```

Which will make the **li** take the length of only the text inside rather than complete **ul**